# How to mock Microsoft Graph APIs GraphServiceClient using moq

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

My project is using GraphServiceClient to get the user Group Names using the below code.This is also using Microsoft.Identity.Web package so GraphServiceClient is injected through constructor.

```
 var group = await graphClient.Me.TransitiveMemberOf
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();
```

The group variable is then used to get the DisplayName of the group.

I want to unit test the above code using NUnit and Moq.

```
 var mockAuthProvider = new Mock<IAuthenticationProvider>();
 var mockHttpProvider = new Mock<IHttpProvider>();
 var mockGraphClient = new Mock<GraphServiceClient>(mockAuthProvider.Object, mockHttpProvider.Object);
    
 mockGraphClient.Setup(c => c.Me.TransitiveMemberOf.Request().GetAsync(CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(???);
```

The ReturnAsync will return IUserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage, but how can I give a default value for it so I can test the rest of the method which actually gets the displayName

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a mock of whatever is being returned and use that

Comment: Show more of the subject under test and the test itself so a proper answer can be provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new instance of `UserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage` and add a new `Group` item to the current page.

```
UserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage page = new 
UserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>(),
};
page.Add(new Group { DisplayName = "MyName" });
```

Return page in `ReturnsAsync` method

```
mockGraphClient.Setup(c => c.Me.TransitiveMemberOf.Request().GetAsync(CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => page);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: how to mock with headers? .Header(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()) not working

Comment: @Yzak what's the exception? Could you share stack trace? Thanks.

Comment: I post it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347490/how-to-mock-graphserviceclient-with-header